# Does bisq have a monero premium when buying?

Tags: p2p-exchange, bisq

Where can one see if bisq has a premium when buying monero using bitcoin or ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

You can check on a service like [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/monero/#markets).